# multiple cardview layouts in one recyclerview in a fragment

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I have figured out how to set up the `RecyclerView.Adapter` with multiple `ViewHolders` for what im wanting to do but i cannot figure out how to show multiple `CardView` layouts in a single `Activity` or `Fragment`. The layout of the `CardView`s always shows the onr for the last set of information retrieved in the Database. Is there a way to have multiple layouts for `CardView`s in a single `Fragment`?

Edit: Here is my adapter

public class TimeCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
    private ArrayList<ChecksGetterSetter> checksList = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final int TYPE_CHECKS = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_CHECKINFO = 1;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    public class ChecksViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        @InjectView(R.id.CCtextviewDate) TextView tvcPayPeriod;
        @InjectView(R.id.CCtextviewHoursInfo) TextView tvcHours;
        @InjectView(R.id.CCtextviewOvertimeHours) TextView cOTHours;
        @InjectView(R.id.CCtextviewOvertimeHoursInfo) TextView tvcOTHours;
        @InjectView(R.id.CCtextviewPayInfo) TextView tvcRate;
        @InjectView(R.id.CCtextviewOvertimePay) TextView cOTRate;
        @InjectView(R.id.CCtextviewOvertimePayInfo) TextView tvcOTRate;
        @InjectView(R.id.CCtextviewGrossPayInfo) TextView tvcGrossPay;
        @InjectView(R.id.CCtextviewAfterTaxInfo) TextView tvcAfterTax;

        public ChecksViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.inject(this, itemView);
        }
    }

    public class CheckInfoViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        @InjectView(R.id.CCItextviewSocialSecurityInfo) TextView tvSocialSecurity;
        @InjectView(R.id.CCItextviewMedicareInfo) TextView tvMedicare;
        @InjectView(R.id.CCItextviewFederalIncomeTaxInfo) TextView tvFederalIncomeTax;
        @InjectView(R.id.CCItextviewAllowancesInfo) TextView tvAllowances;
        @InjectView(R.id.CCItextviewDeductions) TextView deductions;
        @InjectView(R.id.CCItextviewDeductionsInfo) TextView tvDeductions;

        public CheckInfoViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.inject(this, itemView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int viewType;
        if(checksList.get(position).getPeriodStart() != null){
            viewType = TYPE_CHECKS;
        } else {
            viewType = TYPE_CHECKINFO;
        }
        return viewType;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        switch (viewType) {
            case TYPE_CHECKS:
                ViewGroup vgChecks = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_checks, viewGroup, false);
                return new ChecksViewHolder(vgChecks);
            case TYPE_CHECKINFO:
                ViewGroup vgCheckInfo = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_check_info, viewGroup, false);
                return new CheckInfoViewHolder(vgCheckInfo);
            default:
                ViewGroup vgTimeCard1 = (ViewGroup) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_checks, viewGroup, false);
                return new ChecksViewHolder(vgTimeCard1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {

            case TYPE_CHECKS:
                ChecksViewHolder holder = (ChecksViewHolder) viewHolder;
                ChecksGetterSetter pos = checksList.get(position);

                if (pos.getPeriodEnd().equals("") || pos.getPeriodEnd() == null) {
                    holder.tvcPayPeriod.setText(pos.getPeriodStart());
                } else {
                    holder.tvcPayPeriod.setText(pos.getPeriodStart() + " - " + pos.getPeriodEnd());
                }
                holder.tvcHours.setText(pos.getHours());
                if (!pos.getOtHours().equals("0.0")) {
                    holder.tvcOTHours.setText(pos.getOtHours());
                } else {
                    holder.cOTHours.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.tvcOTHours.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                holder.tvcRate.setText(pos.getRate());
                if (!pos.getOtRate().equals("$0.00")) {
                    holder.tvcOTRate.setText(pos.getOtRate());
                } else {
                    holder.cOTRate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.tvcOTRate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                holder.tvcGrossPay.setText(pos.getGrossPay());
                holder.tvcAfterTax.setText(pos.getAfterTax());
                break;

            case TYPE_CHECKINFO:
                CheckInfoViewHolder infoHolder = (CheckInfoViewHolder) viewHolder;
                ChecksGetterSetter posi = checksList.get(position);

                infoHolder.tvSocialSecurity.setText(posi.getSocialSecurity());
                infoHolder.tvMedicare.setText(posi.getMedicare());
                infoHolder.tvFederalIncomeTax.setText(posi.getFederalIncomeTax());
                infoHolder.tvAllowances.setText(posi.getAllowances());
                if (!posi.getDeductions().equals("$0.00")) {
                    infoHolder.tvDeductions.setText(posi.getDeductions());
                } else {
                    infoHolder.deductions.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    infoHolder.tvDeductions.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return checksList.size();
    }

    public ChecksGetterSetter getItem(int position){
        return checksList.get(position);
    }

    public void addItem(ChecksGetterSetter check) {
        checksList.add(check);
        notifyItemInserted(checksList.size() - 1);
    }

    public void deleteItem(int index){
        checksList.remove(index);
        notifyItemRemoved(index);
    }

    public TimeCardAdapter(List<ChecksGetterSetter> check) {
        if(check == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("check must not be null");
        }
        this.checksList = new ArrayList<>(check);
    }
}
```

here is the information i want to populate each of the `ViewHolders` with

```
    private void getCheckInfo() {
        if (checkCursor.getCount() != 0) {
            while (checkCursor.moveToNext()) {
                hours = checkCursor.getDouble(checkCursor.getColumnIndex(ChecksDBAdapter.WORKED));
                overtimeHours = checkCursor.getDouble(checkCursor.getColumnIndex(ChecksDBAdapter.OVERTIMEWORKED));
                payrate = checkCursor.getDouble(checkCursor.getColumnIndex(ChecksDBAdapter.PAYRATE));
                overtimePayrate = checkCursor.getDouble(checkCursor.getColumnIndex(ChecksDBAdapter.OVERTIMEPAYRATE));
                beforeTax = checkCursor.getDouble(checkCursor.getColumnIndex(ChecksDBAdapter.BEFORETAXES));
                afterTax = checkCursor.getDouble(checkCursor.getColumnIndex(ChecksDBAdapter.AFTERTAXES));

                check = new ChecksGetterSetter(
                        "", "",
                        String.valueOf(decimalToTime(hours)),
                        String.valueOf(decimalToTime(overtimeHours)),
                        moneyFormat(payrate),
                        moneyFormat(overtimePayrate),
                        moneyFormat(beforeTax),
                        moneyFormat(afterTax)
                );
                adapter.addItem(check);
            }
        }
    }

    private void getAdditionalCheckInfo() {
        if (checkCursor.getCount() != 0) {
            while (checkCursor.moveToNext()) {
                socialSecurity = checkCursor.getDouble(checkCursor.getColumnIndex(ChecksDBAdapter.SOCIALSECURITY));
                medicare = checkCursor.getDouble(checkCursor.getColumnIndex(ChecksDBAdapter.MEDICARE));
                federalIncomeTax = checkCursor.getDouble(checkCursor.getColumnIndex(ChecksDBAdapter.FEDERALTAXES));
                deductions = checkCursor.getDouble(checkCursor.getColumnIndex(ChecksDBAdapter.DEDUCTIONS));
                allowances = checkCursor.getInt(checkCursor.getColumnIndex(ChecksDBAdapter.ALLOWANCES));

                checkInfo = new ChecksGetterSetter(
                        moneyFormat(socialSecurity),
                        moneyFormat(medicare),
                        moneyFormat(federalIncomeTax),
                        moneyFormat(allowances),
                        moneyFormat(deductions)
                );
                adapter.addItem(checkInfo);
            }
        }
    }
```

after it cycles through `getCheckInfo()` it will populate for the `ViewHolder` just fine but after `getAdditionalCheckInfo()` cycles it replaces the `CardViews` for the first one with the second one and just shows blank cards above them. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a unique view holder, you only need put a list of objects and populate in onBindView, see the example:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainSearchAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<Object> data;

    public CustomAdapter(Lis<Object> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Object object = data.get(position);

        holder.textView.setText("bla");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
           super(itemView);
           textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        }
   }
```